# Upload da Imagem de perfil não é salva

Tags: php

Olá,

Eu tenho um cadastro de usuários aonde é possível inserir uma foto de perfil.Cada vez que tento inserir uma imagem é exibido mensagens de avisos . Já tentei algumas soluções da internet mas infelizmente não consegui resolver o meu problema.

Mensagens:

**"Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in"**

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move**

BD:

Nome  | Tipo

Imagem| blob

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="imagem">Imagem de perfil</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="file" name="imagem" class="btn btn-success"  accept="image/*" > 
</div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']; 
$imagem= $_FILES['imagem']['name']; 
$arqError = $_FILES['imagem']['error'];

if ($arqError == 0) {
        $pasta = './uploads/';
        $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $pasta);
    }
```

PHP para exibir a imagem:

```
<img src="uploads/<?php=$_FILES['imagem']['name'];?>">
```

Comment: O Aviso do PHP está informando que o segundo argumento não pode ser um diretório. É bem provável que não esteja recebendo o nome do arquivo a ser salvo e sim somente o diretório. Tente ver o conteúdo deste argumento utilizado a função `var_dump($argumento);`

Comment: @CarlosAndrade obrigado, vou tentar e no caso ficaria var_dump($imagem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionei no comentário acima, a variável `$pasta` só está recebendo o diretório e não o nome do arquivo. Altere seu código para o seguinte e veja se funciona:

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']; 
$imagem= $_FILES['imagem']['name']; 
$arqError = $_FILES['imagem']['error'];

if ($arqError == 0) {
        $pasta = './uploads/';
        $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $pasta.'imagem.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Funcionou mas antes de votar na tua resposta, poderia fazer um favor? A imagem esta sendo salva mas agora não esta sendo exibida, saberia me dizer do pq?

Comment: Tente o seguinte: `<img src="<?php echo $pasta.'imagem.jpg'; ?>">`

Comment: Primeiro verifique se `$pasta` está realmente recebendo o diretório de uploads. Obs: substitua `imagem.jpg` para uma variável com valor de sua escolha, não deixe assim, caso contrário a cada nova imagem que fizer o upload irá substituir a existente.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, já fiz os ajustes no tua resposta de acordo com a tua sugestão. Porém  eu exibo a foto de perfil numa outra pagina, diferente do cadastro e acredito que seja por isso que tua sugestão de como exibir as fotos não deu certo

Comment: Compreendo. Você deverá então gravar o nome do arquivo no banco de dados (se este for o caso) no momento em que foi salvo a imagem. Então pegar este dado e substituir no exemplo. Ficaria mais ou menos assim: `<img src="<?php echo './uploads/'.$img_perfil; ?>">`

Comment: Desculpa a ignorancia mas não entendi muito bem, eu salvo no BD a `$imagem`. E meu código ficou assim `<img src="<?php echo './uploads/'.$imagem; ?>">`

Comment: Exatamente. No Script do Upload, após o envio você deve gravar no seu cadastro a informação do nome do arquivo para depois então exibi-lo. Por ex: você irá gravar `imagem.jpg` num campo da tabela de cadastro de usuários, você já ter ter estes campos: ID, NOME, LOGIN, etc... Então acrescente um campo IMG_PERFIL e salve neste campo o nome do arquivo do Upload. Na página onde irá exibir a imagem do perfil, leia este campo e armazene numa variável como a do exemplo acima `$imagem`.

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar obrigado pela força!!!

Comment: @Malfus se der certo poste o resultado.

Comment: Não deu certo, fiz desse jeito : `<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT imagem FROM usuarios");
$foto = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
?>
<img src="<?php echo './uploads/'.$foto; ?>">`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61007/discussion-between-carlos-andrade-and-malfus).